# newtype Int -> CInt marshaller

Tags: haskell, types

I'm writing FFI to pdflib. Pdflib C API has lots of functions that return and/or take various handles (document, page, image, font) as plain Integer (not pointer).

In order to ensure i do not accidentally pass the wrong param to a function i create a bunch of newtypes in the form of:

```
newtype PdiDoc = PdiDoc Int
newtype PdiPage = PdiPage Int
newtype PdfImage = PdfImage Int
newtype PdfFont = PdfFont Int
```

Now i need to provide a marshaller for those types.

```
image2c (PdfImage i) = fromIntegral i
font2c (PdfFont f) = fromIntegral f
pdipage2c (PdiPage i) = fromIntegral i
```

As you see the marshallers are exactly the same, just for different types.

So my question is, is there some kind of type magic, SYB vodoo trick that i can use to have just one function to marshall all those types, or do i have to write same functions again and again for different newtypes ?

EDIT: I accepted Don's answer, because it solved my problem.

I switched on

```
GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
```

added

```
deriving (Eq, Ord, Num, Enum, Real, Integral)
```

to each of my newtypes, and now i can use standard fromIntegral to marshall all of them.

Nathan Howell's answer is also correct one, i upvoted it. But unfortunately his solution would mean giving up on FFI preprocessors like c2hs i am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive 'Num' for your types using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, this helps you a bit with literals and operators.

For the marshalling, I'd use a FFI preprocess, such as hsc2hs, which can automate the wrapping and unwrapping of newtypes.

An example [from RWH](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CGsQFjAC&url=http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/interfacing-with-c-the-ffi.html&ei=8WKpT4SfHOL66QGZmtHTBA&usg=AFQjCNEfLoZ8PvE22rE8OgvHw_Itu_1sUQ&sig2=TGVeesQ85mRQC9lcDMfOMg):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i'll check GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving. I am using c2hs. And it requires me to provide a marshaller for any non builtin type. Hence my question.

Answer (score 7):

GHC's FFI extensions allow using newtypes that wrap FFI primitives. You could change the imported function signatures to use the newtypes and (hopefully) avoid having to unwrap them manually.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Main where

newtype Foo = Foo Int

foreign import ccall someCall :: Foo -> IO Foo

main :: IO ()
main = do
  Foo x <- someCall (Foo 1)
  print x
```

Alternatively, the new GHC Generics functionality (available since 7.2.1) allows generic unpacking and repacking of newtypes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Main where

import GHC.Generics

-- use a regular newtype
newtype Foo1 = Foo1 Int deriving (Generic, Show)

-- or with record syntax
newtype Foo2 = Foo2{foo2 :: Int} deriving (Generic, Show)

unpack :: (Generic a, Rep a ~ D1 dc (C1 cc (S1 sc (K1 R kc)))) => a -> kc
unpack = unK1 . unM1 . unM1 . unM1 . from

pack :: (Generic a, Rep a ~ D1 dc (C1 cc (S1 sc (K1 R kc)))) => kc -> a
pack = to . M1 . M1 . M1 . K1

-- the C import uses Ints
foreign import ccall "someCall" c'someCall :: Int -> IO Int

-- and the typed wrapper packs/unpacks to FFI primitives
someCall :: Foo1 -> IO Foo2
someCall = fmap pack . c'someCall . unpack

main :: IO ()
main = do
  Foo2 x <- someCall (Foo1 1)
  print x
```

Comment: I am using c2hs. And it requires me to provide a marshaller for any non builtin type. Is there a way to tell c2hs to just use the type as is without a marshaller ?

Comment: @VagifVerdi I've never used c2hs, so I'm not sure. It looks like they have a newtype keyword but it seems to be used with pointers and not primitives.

Comment: @VagifVerdi I've updated my answer with an alternative generic solution as well. It doesn't need Num/Integral instances either, they seem undesirable for an opaque pointer type.

Comment: Cool solution, thanks. Yours is definitely safer one. I wonder though how much overhead those scary pack/unpack add ? Also the ideal would be to change c2hs to allow to accept newtypes without marshalling. This way no tricks are needed at all.

Comment: @VagifVerdi The generated STG code looks very similar (they get compiled away)... so it's not surprising that it has nearly identical performance, as measured by criterion - well within noise.

Comment: I ended up just editing away all the cruft c2hs introduces and using plain newtypes as you suggested. I'm still gonna keep c2hs generated file for reference, but pdflib is a very simple c library and i can certainly manage handrolled ffi. Thank you.

Comment: Looking at the [docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Generics.html), seems like you can rewrite `M1 D c0 (M1 C c1 (M1 S c2 (K1 R c)))` as `D1 c0 (C1 c1 (S1 c2 (Rec0 c)))`.

Comment: @benmachine I've updated the post with your recommendation. Using ConstraintKinds would also be a reasonable approach here too.